# How do you accept input back from this libraries dialog?

Tags: android

I want to use the library [here](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) to accept a numberpicker. I am wondering how do i receive the data that the user selected in the numberpicker dialog back in my activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity must implements NumberPickerDialogFragment.NumberPickerDialogHandler and

```
@Override
public void onDialogNumberSet(int reference, int number, double decimal, boolean isNegative, double fullNumber) {
    text.setText("Number: " + number + "\nDecimal: " + decimal + "\nIs negative: " + isNegative + "\nFull number: "
            + fullNumber);
}
```

As shown in that library [sample project](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers/blob/master/sample/src/)